# SPFX Web Part Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx-webparts

I am following below MS article to practise jquery integration with SPFX.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part

Getting below error message while i am try to view the results in local workbench with gulp serve

> Error - [tsc] src/webparts/jQueryWebPart/JQueryWebPartWebPart.ts(6,33
>   ): error TS2306: File
>   '.../jquery-webpart/src/webparts/jQueryWebPart/MyAccord
>   ionTemplate.ts' is not a module. Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after
>   9.31 s  exited with code 2

Do i am missing any things? Tried a lot of approach.But no luck.

Comment: What is the version of SPFx and the target platform? How do you import the template in your 'main' file?

Comment: You need to export your template module. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error) question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without looking at your solution, but I have noticed that the instructions say to create your `MyAccordionTemplate.ts` in the `src/webparts/jQuery` folder. The error you get seems to say that you're looking at a file located in `src/webparts/jQueryWebPart/JQueryWebPartWebPart.ts`. Did you rename the web part? If not, take a look that you're using the right paths?

I hope this will help you find the issue?

Comment: I renamed to "JQueryWebPartWebPart" instead of jquery.